# App Engine doesn't recognize file change

Tags: google-app-engine

Often times when i make small changes in my python or html file and upload it to Google App Engine, the changes doesn't seem to apply. I tried clearing my browser cache, and refresh, but still can't see the small change i made in my html file. How do i fix this? how do i know that the changes get uploaded?

Major changes seems to get updated just fine. But if i change a character for example, it doesn't get uploaded. I can't seem to see the change after clearing my browser cache. So, i assume it doesn't get uploaded. Anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in Java with eclipse. I had to clear all my project and close eclipse, reopen it and deploy my app to appEngine..

Hope it help you

Comment: yes, that's what i ended up doing. it's somehow annoying though because uploading to app engine takes about a minute or so.

Answer (score 3):

Does the version in `app.yaml` match the version that's selected as default in the admin console? A mismatch would explain what you're seeing.